# ERROR: RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend

Tags: blazemeter

I haven't been able to find any post related to this issue. I get the following error:

```
12:24:37 ERROR: RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided 
NumPy.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/bzt/1.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bzt/cli.py", line 259, in perform                                                                                                                                  
    self.engine.prepare()                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/bzt/1.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bzt/engine/engine.py", line 214, in prepare                                                                                                                        
    self.__prepare_aggregator()                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/bzt/1.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bzt/engine/engine.py", line 696, in __prepare_aggregator                                                                                                           
    self.aggregator = self.instantiate_module(cls)                                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/bzt/1.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bzt/engine/engine.py", line 483, in instantiate_module                                                                                                             
    classobj = self.__load_module(alias)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/bzt/1.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bzt/engine/engine.py", line 468, in __load_module                                                                                                                  
    self.modules[alias] = load_class(clsname)                                                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/bzt/1.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bzt/utils.py", line 981, in load_class                                                                                                                             
    module = __import__(module_name)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/bzt/1.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bzt/modules/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>                                                                                                                     
    from bzt.modules.aggregator import ConsolidatingAggregator                                                                                                                                                                              
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/bzt/1.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bzt/modules/aggregator.py", line 27, in <module>                                                                                                                   
    from hdrpy import HdrHistogram, RecordedIterator                                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/bzt/1.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hdrpy/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>                                                                                                                           
    import numpy                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/bzt/1.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 286, in <module>                                                                                                                          
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
```

when I try to run `bzt` from the commandline. Has anyone encountered this issue? If so were you able to figure out where it was coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hitting this same issue, but upgrading my install fixed it for me.

If you used homebrew like I did:
`brew upgrade bzt`

**EDIT:** 
it actually seems to be a different issue. When I clear the log folders it seems to work (or at least throws a different error)

**EDIT 2:** 
Sorry for the double edit :p But I figured out the solution.

**It looks like you need to use Python version 3.6.9 (or posibbly earler)**.  But running the blazemeter tests on their cloud servers shows they use python 3.6.9. So I used that locally and it solved this bug for me.

Btw - if you haven't used pyenv to handle local python versions I highly recommend :)